# Generate children tree in a game for alpha beta algorithm using python

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have one game which consists of a 6x6 board and 6 pieces in each side of the board, x and o, that are opponents. In order to perform the alpha beta search algorithm I need to generate the possible children. 
The allowed moves are vertical, horizontal and diagonal, and a piece can jump above other piece that is located n squares away if it can be positioned n squares away from the piece.
and it can go backward and foward.
The goal of the game is to go to the oposite side.
I made a matrix[5][5] representing the board and the following heuristics code:

```
def heuristic_evaluation(node,player):
h = 0
if(player == "x"):
    h += node[0][1] + 5
if(player == "o"):
    h += node[0][1] - 5
return h
```

Where the node is a pair with the "wanted" coordinates of the board.

To evaluate the possible moves I made this function:

```
def is_allowed(board,move,player):
if((board[move[2]][move[3]] == "x") or (board[move[2]][move[3]] == "o")): #if is something in the square
    return False
if(board[move[0]][move[1]] == player): #if the piece in the square is of the current player
    if( (move[2] == (move[0] + 1)) or (move[2] == (move[0] - 1)) or ( (move[2] == move[0]) and ( (move[1] == (move[3] -1)) or (move[1] == (move[3]+1)) ) )): #trying to evaluate possible moves without the jumping factor yet
        return True
    else:
        return False
else:
    return False
```

I want to know if there's a way to improve my heuristic evaluation and also how to generate the children tree. Can you help me, please?